# Shade and insert labels in a triangular region with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I need to plot a triangle with vertices `(0,0)`, `(1,2)`, `(0,3)` with x & y coordinate axes (and labels), and tick marks on the axes. How can I accomplish this in TikZ.

My code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[->] (-5.0,0) -- (5.0,0) node[right] {$x$} coordinate(x axis); 
\draw[->] (0,-5.0) -- (0,5.0) node[above] {$y$} coordinate(y axis); 
\draw (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (0,3) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But, how do I get the points labeled and shade in the region?

Comment: I have part of this below:          \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-5.0,0) -- (5.0,0) node[right] {$x$} coordinate(x axis);
\draw[->] (0,-5.0) -- (0,5.0) node[above] {$y$} coordinate(y axis);

\draw (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (0,3) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}                                       But, how do I get the points labeled and shade in the region? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[top color=white,bottom color=red] (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (0,3) -- cycle; 

\foreach \coordinate/\label/\pos in {{(0,0)/label1/above left},{(1,2)/label2/right},{(0,3)/label3/above right}}
\node[\pos] at \coordinate {\label};

\draw[->] (-5.0,0) -- (5.0,0) node[right] {$x$} coordinate(x axis); 
\draw[->] (0,-5.0) -- (0,5.0) node[above] {$y$} coordinate(y axis); 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

The key points are basically two:

1. the `foreach` that allows to specify in one shot the `coordinate` (i.e. (0,0)) in which the `label` will be placed in a given `position` (i.e. `above left`);
2. the use of the `shadings` library that allows to shade the region; in the example the shading is vertical, but it is possible to insert different type of shadings (see 47 Shadings Library from the pgfmanual version April 25, 2012 / 46
   Shadings Library from the pgfmanual version October 25, 2010).

Answer (score 4):

A solution with tikz and tkz-euclide

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{polygons} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5]     
   \tkzAxeXY
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}   
   \tkzDefPoint(1,2){B}
   \tkzDefPoint(0,3){C}   
   \tkzDrawPolygon[top color=white,bottom color=red](A,B,C)
   \tkzLabelPoints[above right](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using the `patch` plot type of pgfplots:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[patch,shader=interp]
    table[point meta=\thisrow{c}] {
        x y c
        % first patch:
        0 0 0.2
        1 1 0
        2 0 1

        % second patch:
        1 1 0
        2 0 -1
        3 1 0

        % third patch:
        2 0 0.5
        3 1 1
        4 0 0.5
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and with labels and continuos shading:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[patch,shader=interp]
    table[point meta=\thisrow{c}] {
        x y c
        % first patch:
        0 0 0.2
        1 1 0
        2 0 1

        % second patch:
        1 1 0
        2 0 1
        3 1 0

        % third patch:
        2 0 1
        3 1 0
        4 0 0.5
    };
    \addplot[only marks,nodes near coords] % this produces labels
    table[point meta=explicit symbolic,meta=labels] {
        x y labels
        0 0 $a$
        1 1 $b$
        2 0 $c$
        3 1 $d$
        4 0 $e$
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

It uses a default axis configuration and reads points from an input table. The table has three columns: one for x, one for y, and one for the color data. The color data is mapped linearly into a `colormap` which can be configured, what you see is the default. The `shader=interp` tells pgfplots to produce a linear shading between the three corners and is color data.

The second graphics has two plots in the same axis: one which produces the geometry and one which produces `nodes near coords`. This is a special scatter plot which assumes that `point meta` contains the content of nodes which are placed at the input coordinates. In this case, I used `point meta=explicit symbolic` which, for table input, means that the `meta` column contains textual data. I chose `meta=labels` to idenfity the "labels" column which contains math mode text.

You may also be interested in

- `axis lines=left` which does not produce a box but axis lines on their lower ("left") limits,
- three dimensional plots with `\addplot3` (and one more table column)
- other input formats (coordinates as in your example is also supported, even with color data)
- details for the encountered options + more examples in the pdf manual on http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

The following is rather close to what you're after I guess:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \draw[->] (-5.0,0) -- (5.0,0) node[right] {$x$} coordinate(x axis);
  % Loop to generate ticks and labels
  \foreach \i in {-5,-4,...,5}
  \draw (\i,-2 pt) -- (\i,2 pt) node[above]{$\i$};
  \draw[->] (0,-5.0) -- (0,5.0) node[above] {$y$} coordinate(y axis); 
  \foreach \i in {-5,-4,...,5}
  \draw (-2 pt,\i) -- (2 pt,\i) node[right]{$\i$};
  \draw[red,fill] (0,0) node[left]{$a$} -- (1,2) node[right]{$b$} -- (0,3) node[left]{$c$} -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Most of the things are basic and can be found in the manual or in the [wonderful repository](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) of examples.